# Prerouting Docker IPv6 traffic to a different container with IP Tables

Tags: iptables, docker, ipv6

I created a docker network with:

```
SUBNET=/64 network segment
docker network create docker network create --ipv6 --subnet ${SUBNET}:d::/80 --gateway ${SUBNET}:d::1 mynet
```

Now I am running a container on `${SUBNET}:d::2` and `${SUBNET}:d::[3-X]` with

```
docker run --rm --net mynet --ip6 ${SUBNET}:d:2 --name nginx -p 8080:80 nginx:latest
docker run --rm --net mynet --ip6 ${SUBNET}:d:3 --name alp -it alpine:latest ash
```

The containers on [3-X] will not expose any port but they will receive connections on that port (Its actually sockets but testing it with nginx is easier). Any traffic on port 8080 that comes in on those IPs should be redirected to the container exposing 8080 on `${SUBNET}:d::2`

I tried adding a DNAT rulelike this:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d ${SUBNET}:d::3 --dport 9033 -j DNAT --to-destination [${SUBNET}:d::2]:9033
```

and then `telnet ${SUBNET}:d::3 9033` which does not work though it works on the `::2`. Also tried brackets on the -d address like this which results in an error which I suspect is the root cause:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d [${SUBNET}:d::3] --dport 9033 -j DNAT --to-destination [${SUBNET}:d::2]:9033
---> 
ip6tables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): host/network `[$SUBNET:d::3]' not found
Try `ip6tables -h' or 'ip6tables --help' for more information.
```

Removing the `-d` parameter all together has the same non working effect but does not give any errors.

Comment: I will mention a couple of things. First, you really should not use IPv6 network sizes other than `/64` because you can break some IPv6 features. Next, IPv6 does not have NAT the way IPv4 does. There is the _Experimental_ _[RFC 6296, IPv6-to-IPv6 Network Prefix Translation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6296)_, but it defines a one-to-one NAT, and it explicitly forbids the typical many-to-one NAPT commonly used by IPv4. IPv6 was designed to remove the need for NAPT by providing a huge address space that restores the IP paradigm of unique addresses, and doing that can break some IPv6 features.

Comment: Thats easier said then done. Docker needs at least a /80 network but cannot work on the /64 network as that would overlap with the IPs the system itself would use (the $SUBNET::2/64 one) and it needs a base CIDR. I also need to create a subnet in docker which is not overlapping with the base CIDR (which is also a /80) because otherwise I cannot give fixed IPs to the started containers.

All in all I am totally aware that this is not something you would advise doing and that it is a hack for a problem that is not supposed to happen but for my case it does.

Comment: Why is the redirection to the 2 container needed in the first place? Can the connections be routed by proxy?

Comment: If the docker is using a different network, anyway (you are already creating a separate network for the docker, so you must be routing between that network and the host network), why not give docker its own `/64` network that is different than the `/64` network used by the host? If you start using other sized networks, you are setting yourself up for problems. Given a standard `/48` prefix delegation, you have 65,536 different `/64` networks, so trying to conserve addressing does not make sense, and it is usually counterproductive for IPv6, which is designed to waste addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin cause I only have a /64 space Subnet available in the first place. So I need to reduce it for the default docker bridge anyways and I need to create a snd docker network because the default bridge does not allow to pass the IP I want the container to have to. John the application on ::2 needs to be available on all IPs directly that also serve on the ::3+ they are kinda a unit each but  the goal is to only have one unit of A running and several Units formed.

Comment: Your ISP should be delegating your business a /48 prefix. Only residential Internet connections get /64, but that is really wrong, too.

Comment: Well its just a dedicated server. And I don't see at all how that would actually solve the problem. Docker needs at least a /80 network to work correctly and so far it worked for me with putting /80 and using the provided /64s I get on servers.

Comment: @JohnMahowald the proxy input seems the right direction so I am actually one step further. All that routing does not work as expected cause docker by default opens all ports in ipv6 network to public and you shouldn't bind the ports to the host...